# Capturar Nível de Qualidade de Compressão da Imagem PHP

Tags: php, imagick

Preciso capturar o nível de qualidade de uma imagem, achei algo relativo no `[Imagick][1]`

Tentativa de uso:

```
    $img = new Imagick();
    $img->readImage( $local_da_imagem );
    print_r( $img->getCompressionQuality() );
```

mas, este retorno sempre é `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido

```
$img = new Imagick();
$img->readImage( $local_da_imagem );
echo $img->getImageCompressionQuality() ;
```

Assim é retornado o nível de qualidade da imagem, indo de `0` a `100`, quanto mais alto, melhor a qualidade.